# Does sum function description exist in CQL?

Tags: java, cassandra, sum, cql

I can easyly execute a query from DevCenter:

```
SELECT sum(count) FROM myTable;
```

But I do not find any focumentation on `sum` function in `cql`. Is it exists? Where cassandra team published function list with `count` function and others?

**Note**

[This function list](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cql_function_r.html) tell nothing about `count` or `sum`.

Comment: "CQL supports several functions that transform one or more column values into a new value. Aggregation functions are not supported."

Answer (score 4):

The sum() and avg() functions appear to work in Cassandra 2.2 and the 3.0-alpha for SELECT statements, but they don't seem to be in the documentation yet.

They should probably be documented in the 2.2 CQL reference [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html).  I imagine they will make a big effort to update the documentation when 3.0 is officially released.

They seem pretty easy to use:

```
cqlsh:test> CREATE table t1 ( a int, b int, primary key (a));
cqlsh:test> INSERT INTO t1 (a, b) VALUES ( 1, 2);
cqlsh:test> INSERT INTO t1 (a, b) VALUES ( 3, 4);
cqlsh:test> SELECT sum (b) from t1;

 system.sum(b)
---------------
             6

(1 rows)
cqlsh:test> SELECT avg (b) from t1;

 system.avg(b)
---------------
             3
```

It's nice to finally have basic aggregation functions built in.  Now if someone would just implement basic joins using a Spark like approach we'd be cooking with gas. :)

To answer your question a little more, the functions appear to be implemented in this file (if you download the source code):

```
src/java/org/apache/cassandra/cql3/functions/AggregateFcts.java
```

The functions implemented in Cassandra 2.2 are: sum(), avg(), max(), min(), and count().

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra doesn't support aggregate functions as part of the CQL standard. But starting with Cassandra 2.2, you'll be able to create your own functions ([UDA](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDA.html)), which would allow you to implement a sum calculation.